# Occurence of an integer in a column - Add as a new column

Tags: linux, unix, awk, bioinformatics, tabular

I have a tabular file with 6 columns. What I need to do, is to add a 7th column that counts the occurrence of the value from the column 3. I did it with Excel, adding the formula

```
=countif(C:C,$C1)
```

But the files are huge, and I have lots of them

For example:

My input is this one:

```
0   SL3.0ch03   7675648 21M GATCACTCCAAACTCATCATA   NM:i:2
0   SL3.0ch03   7675648 21M GATCACTCCAAACTCATCATA   NM:i:2
0   SL3.0ch03   7675648 21M GATCACTCCAAACTCATCATA   NM:i:2
0   SL3.0ch03   7675649 21M ATCACTCCAAACTCATCATAC   NM:i:1
0   SL3.0ch03   7675649 21M ATCACTCCAAACTCATCATAC   NM:i:1
0   SL3.0ch03   7675649 21M CTCACTCCAAACTCATCATAC   NM:i:2
0   SL3.0ch03   7675649 21M ATCACTCCAAACTCATCATAC   NM:i:1
0   SL3.0ch03   7675649 21M ATCACTCCAAACTCATCATAC   NM:i:1
0   SL3.0ch03   7675650 21M TCACTCCAAACTCATCATACT   NM:i:1
0   SL3.0ch03   7675650 21M TCACTCCAAACTCATCATACT   NM:i:1
0   SL3.0ch03   7675650 21M TCACTCCAAACTCATCATACT   NM:i:1
0   SL3.0ch03   7675650 21M TCACTCCAAACTCATCATACT   NM:i:1
```

And I need an output like this one:

```
0   SL3.0ch03   7675648 21M GATCACTCCAAACTCATCATA   NM:i:2  3
0   SL3.0ch03   7675648 21M GATCACTCCAAACTCATCATA   NM:i:2  3
0   SL3.0ch03   7675648 21M GATCACTCCAAACTCATCATA   NM:i:2  3
0   SL3.0ch03   7675649 21M ATCACTCCAAACTCATCATAC   NM:i:1  5
0   SL3.0ch03   7675649 21M ATCACTCCAAACTCATCATAC   NM:i:1  5
0   SL3.0ch03   7675649 21M CTCACTCCAAACTCATCATAC   NM:i:2  5
0   SL3.0ch03   7675649 21M ATCACTCCAAACTCATCATAC   NM:i:1  5
0   SL3.0ch03   7675649 21M ATCACTCCAAACTCATCATAC   NM:i:1  5
0   SL3.0ch03   7675650 21M TCACTCCAAACTCATCATACT   NM:i:1  4
0   SL3.0ch03   7675650 21M TCACTCCAAACTCATCATACT   NM:i:1  4
0   SL3.0ch03   7675650 21M TCACTCCAAACTCATCATACT   NM:i:1  4
0   SL3.0ch03   7675650 21M TCACTCCAAACTCATCATACT   NM:i:1  4
```

I've tried a few things that I found:

```
awk '{h[$3]++}; END { for(k in h) print k, h[k] }' input.tab
```

That actually displays the 7th column, but not the rest. I also found that this code:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}'
```

prints all the columns, so I thought "this should work":

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7};{h[$3]++}; END { for(k in h) print k, h[k] }' input.tab > output.tab
```

but it obviously didn't. The best thing I could achieve was to print all 6 original columns and the output I need at the bottom of the file, but I need it as a 7th column.

I'm familiar with basic shell commands, but not with AWK language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you'll have to read the file twice for this to work, which depending on size, can be pretty inefficient.

Either way, you were close:
`awk '{h[$3]++}; END { for(k in h) print k, h[k] }' input.tab` 
is building a map in `h[]` keyed on the value of `$3` and storing the count of it's occurrences, then after all lines are read, printing out that map.

What you want seems like this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{h[$3]++;next} {$7=h[$3]; print}' input.tab input.tab
```

The first read through the file we build the map of `$3` to it's count like you were, then the second read (when `FNR!=NR`) we add that value as `$7`, then print the resulting line out.

e.g.

```
$awk 'FNR==NR{h[$3]++;next} {$7=h[$3]; print}' input.tab input.tab
0 SL3.0ch03 7675648 21M GATCACTCCAAACTCATCATA NM:i:2 3
0 SL3.0ch03 7675648 21M GATCACTCCAAACTCATCATA NM:i:2 3
0 SL3.0ch03 7675648 21M GATCACTCCAAACTCATCATA NM:i:2 3
0 SL3.0ch03 7675649 21M ATCACTCCAAACTCATCATAC NM:i:1 5
0 SL3.0ch03 7675649 21M ATCACTCCAAACTCATCATAC NM:i:1 5
0 SL3.0ch03 7675649 21M CTCACTCCAAACTCATCATAC NM:i:2 5
0 SL3.0ch03 7675649 21M ATCACTCCAAACTCATCATAC NM:i:1 5
0 SL3.0ch03 7675649 21M ATCACTCCAAACTCATCATAC NM:i:1 5
0 SL3.0ch03 7675650 21M TCACTCCAAACTCATCATACT NM:i:1 4
0 SL3.0ch03 7675650 21M TCACTCCAAACTCATCATACT NM:i:1 4
0 SL3.0ch03 7675650 21M TCACTCCAAACTCATCATACT NM:i:1 4
0 SL3.0ch03 7675650 21M TCACTCCAAACTCATCATACT NM:i:1 4
```

Also, if these are truly tab delimited,you'll want to add `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` to set the delimiter and output delimiter to tab, as it defaults to space as my output above shows.

`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} FNR==NR{h[$3]++;next} {$7=h[$3]; print}' input.tab input.tab`

Comment: `{print $0. h[$3]}` or `{$7=h[$3]}1` might be better.  Also `input.tab{,}` eliminates double typing the filename.

Comment: Thanks a lot zzevannn, this worked just fine! And thanks karakfa for the suggestion, as well!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that records with the same 3rd field are consecutive:

```
awk 'b!=$3{for(j=0;j<i;j++){print a[j],i};delete a;b=$3;i=0;}{a[i++]=$0}END{for (j=0;j<i;j++){print a[j],i}}' file
```

details:

```
awk '
    b!=$3 { # when the stored 3rd field is different from the current
        for(j=0;j<i;j++){ print a[j],i }; # display stored records
        delete a; # delete the array
        b=$3; # store the current "new" field
        i=0;
    }
    { a[i++]=$0 } # store the current record and increment the index
    # display the last stored records
    END {for (j=0;j<i;j++){print a[j],i}}
' file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it also worked! And thank you for the explanation, too!